# EKS cluster created by kops does not appear in AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kops

#### Issue 1

The question says it all. I can't find the EKS cluster which was created by kops in the AWS console. I can, however, interact with it as the IAM user (`kops-user`) which I used to launch the cluster, using `kops` and `kubectl` commands. The following policies are directly attached to `kops-user`:

```
AmazonEC2FullAccess
AmazonRoute53FullAccess
AmazonS3FullAccess
IAMFullAccess
AmazonVPCFullAccess
```

Here was the command I used to launch the cluster:

```
kops create cluster \
  --cloud aws \
  --vpc ${VPC_ID} \
  --subnets ${SUBNET1_ID},${SUBNET2_ID},${SUBNET3_ID} \
  --zones ap-southeast-1a,ap-southeast-1b,ap-southeast-1c \
  --networking calico \
  --master-size t3.medium --master-count 1 \
  --node-size t3.medium --node-count 1 \
  --dns-zone dev.mgamer.io \
  ${CLUSTER_NAME}
```

The Kubernetes cluster itself is working fine.

Why can't the `root` user see the cluster in the AWS console? How can this be fixed?

#### Issue 2

The other issue that I can't figure out is that, why does my user, `kops-user`, who already has all those powerful policies attached to it, is still unable to run `aws eks list-clusters`?

```
lester:hello lester$ aws sts get-caller-identity
Account: '459567475699'
Arn: arn:aws:iam::459567475699:user/kops-user
UserId: SGLJI8490SG9D3IGLSK
lester:hello lester$ aws eks list-clusters
clusters: []
lester:hello-mgamer lester$
```

What other permission does it need?

I even tried adding a custom policy and attached it to the `kops-user`, with no luck:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Issue 1**:

- The Kubernetes Cluster that kops creates is with EC2 instances, not with EKS.

**Issue 2**

- Is the same answer from issue 1, it's not listing any EKS clusters because kops doesn't create one.